pyenv recognises .python-version file but ignores it when running python
Observe this output from my terminal:
❯ cat .python-version
3.10.12
❯ pyenv local
3.10.12
❯ pyenv version
3.10.12 (set by /path/to/current/dir/.python-version)
❯ pyenv which python
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.12/bin/python

So pyenv clearly thinks I'm going to use 3.10.12.
However, when I run python it uses a different interpreter:
❯ python --version
Python 3.12.6
❯ which python
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.12.6/bin/python

Why is pyenv not causing me to use 3.10 ?

Hmmm, I just started a new shell
eval $SHELL

and now its using the correct version
❯ pyenv local
3.10.12
❯ python --version
Python 3.10.12

I've no idea what I've changed to make it work. Bizarre.
